# Create a dynamic programming algorithm to compute the fibonacci sequence using tetranacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic, pseudocode, divide-and-conquer

I have been asked to create a dynamic programming algorithm to compute a generalization of the Fibonacci sequence using Tetranacci numbers defined as follows:

> T(0) = 0, T(1) = 1, T(2) = 1, T(3) = 2, and the recurrence relation T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + T(n - 3) + T(n - 4)

The problem is, I am unsure whether or not my algorithm is considered a "dynamic" algorithm, whereas there are still (many) input values that could be computed more than once. Here's what I have:

```
//n is the value being computed (Tn)
tetranacci(n)
    if n = 0 then
        return 0;
    else if n = 1 or n = 2 then
        return 1;
    else if n = 3 then
        return 2
    else
        return tetranacci(n - 1) + tetranacci(n - 2) + tetranacci(n - 3) + tetranacci(n - 4)
```

If this is correct can someone clarify for me what makes this dynamic? I'm having trouble finding a strict definition online. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's just a recursive algorithm.  You are probably supposed to add memoization for it to be a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Hmm... I can understand how I'd do that, but I don't understand why the prof would tell me to use Tetranacci numbers in that case. Couldn't I just as easily do that with the regular Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Sure, but it is even more effective on tetranacci numbers (when it's done right), and also he/she may have wanted to make it harder for students to just Google an answer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ahh, I see. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @RBarryYoung I posted an answer, does it look right to you?

Comment: or [T(-2) = T(-1) = T(0) = 0, T(1) = 1](http://oeis.org/search?q=0,1,1,2,4,8,15&go=Search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got to the bottom of it. Simply use an array to store values as they are computed:

```
//n is the value being computed (Tn), A is an array containing already-computed values for n
tetranacci(n)
    if n = 0 then
        return 0;
    else if n = 1 or n = 2 then
        return 1;
    else if n = 3 then
        return 2
    else if A[n] != null
        return A[n]
    else
        A[n] = tetranacci(n - 1) + tetranacci(n - 2) + tetranacci(n - 3) + tetranacci(n - 4)
        return A[n]
```

Comment: You can simplify the function by initializing the first 4 entries of `A`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, but that makes it tougher to make it a recursive algorithm w/o redundant calls

Comment: Not really.  You can just remove the explicit tests for 0, 1, 2, and 3 and just keep the final `if`.

Comment: @chqrlie True, but I'd need to set the values in the array ahead of time. I suppose since this is just pseudo code, it doesn't really matter, and I could just write that the first 4 values of the array must be initialized to that. But in practice it would require an outside method to set the values, is all.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to implement a dynamic programming algorithm completely without recursive calls as follows in C#.

```
int Tetranacci(int n)
{
    var NumOfStates = Math.Max(n + 1, 4);  // accomodate enough space
    var States = new int[NumOfStates];     // to contain all initial values
    States[0] = 0;                         // initialize first states
    States[1] = 1;
    States[2] = 1;
    States[3] = 2;
    for (int i = 4; i < n; i++)            // iterate up to desired value
    {
        States[i] = States[i-1] + States[i-2] + States[i-3] + States[i-4];
    }
    return States[n];
}
```

Comment: This is not dynamic, merely iterative.  Furthermore, you do not need to allocate an array, 4 states are sufficient for this computation. Index into an array of 4 ints modulo 4.

Comment: Good point on the reduction of the state space. However, what exactly would be _dynamic_ opposed to _iterative_ then?

Comment: Dynamic programming is well described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming .  You break the problem into small tasks for which you store the results in an intermediary data structure.  See the other answer by user3495690.

Comment: To my understanding, the specific paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence) describes the approach in my answer (however with reduced state space and for the Fibonacci sequence) as _bottom-up_ dynamic progamming; am I missing some key point here? I don't see how this approach would _not_ be termed dynamic programming.

Comment: In your code, you do not use memoization as described in the Wikipedia article and user3495690's answer.  Each call to your function computes the result from scratch by testing `4` values and iterating `n-4` times.